# Full HD Android Emulator

Tags: android, emulation, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to emulate a device with 1920X1080 resolution, but when i start the avd only a blank screen is displayed.
Also, i'm aware of the android emulator limitation, but can we find an workaround to this problem?

Comment: You could give Genymotion a try. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/18871458/1491212

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed using AndroVM http://androvm.org/blog/, also is a faster alternative to android emulator

Answer (score 0):

There is another option using the regular AVD. The problem is in the "use Host GPU" - it should be checked. I had the same problem - blank screen and AVD won't run. I edited the AVD settings and checked the "use Host GPU" - it works.