# Creating Galaxy S4 emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, samsung-mobile

I am trying to run my app specifically on Galaxy S4. But I do not have the real time device. So, I'm trying to create the emulator for Galaxy S4. I have a normal Core I3 system with 4GB RAM. It doesn't have any graphics card and all.

I am finding the ways for installing the Samsung Galaxy S4 add-ons to my sdk. But I am not getting it.

I referred these links,

[Android Galaxy S4 Emulator Not Opening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978179/android-galaxy-s4-emulator-not-opening)

[How to test android app in Galaxy S4 configuration using emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646398/how-to-test-android-app-in-galaxy-s4-configuration-using-emulator/16646536#16646536)

http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Using-Samsung-Emulators-for-Android-Application-Development

http://developer.samsung.com/board/list.do?ctgy1=1&ctgy2=1&menu=EN01010301&srchYn=Y&pageIndex=1&pageSize=10&search=

However, I am unable to get any results with these.

Then I referred this alternative for Galaxy S4 i.e., installing Sony add-on for Xperia Z which has the same config as S4. And I am able to create a Xperia Z avd. I have checked "Use Host GPU"  option also. But still, the screen appears to be totally black.

http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/sony-add-on-sdk/install-the-sony-add-on-sdk/

So can any body tell me how to install S4 add on so that I can create an emulator for it.

**Update:**

RAM Allocated: 256MB
HeapSize: 64
And I have modified the screen size to 4.0 inches to adjust to my system.

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is how I created my S4 emulator and working perfectly.

Go to "Android VirtualDevice Manager" -> Device Manager -> New Device and fill in like this:

[image]

Or follow this tutorial:

http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/sony-add-on-sdk/install-the-sony-add-on-sdk/

Comment: Restart eclipse / computer, close all your emulators. Then it should load.

Comment: Will check and tell you

Comment: I have already installed this to my sdk. I have created an emulator also but it is also displaying black screen only

Comment: And I restarted everything as you said, but still no result :(

Comment: I don't know what was wrong with my system. I tested this in some other system. There with some modification, it worked. But this will not be having the ppi as that of real device right

Comment: Just the heads up. S4 is not considered by Android to be a "large" device. [According to the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), large devices should be at least 640dp x 480dp, and Samsung Galaxy S4 is 640dp x 360dp (1920x1080 @xxhdpi, 480dpi), so it falls in the bucket of normal devices (at least 470dp x 320dp)

Comment: @tejas try setting RAM to 768MB. 200MB isn't enough to load it, I think.

Comment: Unfortunately, the android emulator consideres the specification in this answer as a "large" screen, and loads the wrong layout file. What to do about that?

Answer (score 14):

You can check [Samsung RTL](http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlDeviceList.action). It will be very useful for testing. Just create a new credential and use any of available devices.

Comment: I created and ran a S4 device also. But how to run my application there? When I give Run Android Application from eclipse it won't list right. And also it is not possible to view the LogCat then

Comment: Just goto above Samsung RTL(Samsung Remote Testing Lab) link. You have got the original device placed in Samsung Lab. Just install your .apk and test the app. But first you need to create a new user/registration.

Comment: I got it, I am done with registration. But my stupid question, how can I place my apk there?

Comment: Friend just select the device and download it. Just click above part on device it provide option to install the .apk. 

Also, If you need Just let me know if you find any difficulty. I am always with you to help.

Comment: I am here, just try and let me know.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139241/remote-test-laboratory-rtl-for-android

Comment: From the device list, I selected the Galaxy S4 and Reserved for 45 minutes. Then clicked Start. That time it says, Reservation should have 15 minute safety margins and must not overlap with another reservation. And device is not started :(

Comment: Actually I could start device around 1.5 hours back. But now I am not able to create. And it has been listed under Test History

Comment: Currently I am reserve a Samsung S3 and test my demo app. Just try :).

Comment: Yea I reserved a Note 2. But I want it to run on S4 only and also my credits are only 13 now :(

Comment: Can you see the screenshot I attached in the question

Comment: okay, you got the credit on daily basis and now Galaxy S4 is reserved by some other developer like us. Just try after some time. I think if device will be available then I m sure that this will allot to you.

Comment: Oh ok, but I din't understand hwo to install apk on that device. Does that have internet?

Comment: Just take little bit patience because developer is more as compare to the devices in RTL and developer from whole world can access them.

Comment: Sure,I agree with you. But can you please tell me the procedure for installing the apk if you don't mind

Comment: Once you got the virtual device, Just right click on the header part of device. It will ask for installation. Just provide the path of the .apk it will begin the procedure of installation and from app section you can see your app.

Comment: Ok, small clarification. Header part of the device means you meant top Settings section?

Comment: No, Once you got virtual device. Just right click on any part above the screen. You can also right click on place near to "Samsung" name of device.

Comment: Oh ok. I will try this. But we cannot see logs right in this case. It would have been better if I had an emulator. DO you have any idea on that? Also we have time freedom there

Comment: Sure, Just let me know your response. Also if this answer help you then please accept so that other can use it and save their time.

Comment: Sure, I will test and do that. I have already upvoted for helping :) thank you very much

Comment: Hey, I got the device. Can you wait for a while? I am running it

Comment: Welcome, My pleasure to help you. Okay

Comment: It has not yet loaded the screen :(

Comment: ohhh, what issue you have received. Some time network will play a difficult  role here. Just try again and again.

Comment: It is just showing as Loading screen, no progress. I cannot exit also right

Comment: Also, you can check here https://www.manymo.com/emulators. You got online simulator. Just select one as per your Galaxy S4 requirements. And I am sure this load in little time.

Comment: Yes it take time to load and must ensure you have a high speed network connectivity.

Comment: RTL is saying either the server down or problem with my network.And in that link I don't get S4 specs, 1080*1920 :(

Comment: ohh Sorry, Let me check with other technique. I will post here ASAP. Just give me some time. I am really very sorry :(.

Comment: Sure, hey no need to say Sorry, thank you for helping. Will wait for that

Comment: You can check here http://androvm.org/blog/androvm-documentation/, This environment provide support for each type of devices. 

Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527619/full-hd-android-emulator

Comment: @Amith, I downloaded this genymotion-1.2.1_x86.bin from the link. But it is not installing :(

Answer (score 8):

Try using [Genymotion](http://genymotion.com/). It provides a built-in image for Galaxy S4/HTC One/Xperia Z (running Android 4.2.2). While it does not emulate any S4 specific software, it does provide a pretty good hardware match.

Comment: I downloaded and this is the file genymotion-1.2.1_x86.bin. But how to install it. I am in ubuntu

Comment: Go to [this](https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/doc/) page and click the **Installation** heading for install instructions. You will also need to install VirtualBox - which should be available through the **Ubuntu Software Center**.

Comment: I tried a small app of mine on the Genymotion image for S4 4.2.2. Everything works perfectly fine. I then tried it on 2 real S4: the app crashes straight. So unfortunately I guess the emulation is not perfect indeed.

Comment: That's to be expected as there is no way to emulate the **software** changes made by Samsung. The only way to be 100% sure is to test on an actual device. But for most apps it should work just fine on the emulator.

Comment: Genymotion seems to be a great tip if you need an emulator, cheers

Answer (score 5):

I am on mac-OSX and setting "Use Host GPU" solved the problem