# Xamarin screen is always blank

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-emulator

I am trying to learn creating a mobile application using xamarin. I created simple application that says "hello World" on the mainpage.xaml.

Below is the code for mainpage.xaml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App1"
             x:Class="App1.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label

                Text="Welcome to Hello World  website" />
            <Label Text="A Second Line" FontSize="Large"></Label>


        </StackLayout>

    </ContentPage.Content>

    <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin Forms!" 
           VerticalOptions="Center" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center" />

</ContentPage>
```

I installed all the updates using android sdk manager and I am using Visual studio 2017. when I run the application, I keep getting this error:

```
   C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1\tools\emulator.EXE -partition-size 512 -no-boot-anim -avd VisualStudio_android-23_arm_phone -prop monodroid.avdname=VisualStudio_android-23_arm_phone
     3>emulator: ERROR: cmd_camera_device_start_capturing: Device 'AndroidEmulatorVC0' is unable to save frame to the clipboard: 0
```

the emulator screen is always black. I don't see anything on the emulator screen. Below is the screen shot of android SDK manager. I am not sure if I am missing any update.

[image: SDK Image]

any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Android emulators has quite bad reputation in terms of stability and performance. You might want to try [alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112889/alternatives-to-the-android-avd-emulator). There is [one blogpost in Japanese](http://sankusu2525.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/01/29/114512) that describes how to solve the problem (use Google translate).

Additionally, the shared XAML example is invalid. `ContentPage` can contain only one root element, the example has 2. So it should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App1"
             x:Class="App1.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Welcome to Hello World  website" />
            <Label Text="A Second Line" FontSize="Large" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Beside that I would strongly recommend to use [XAMLC](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc/), it will let you know if there are any problems with your XAML while compilation.