# How can I speed up ARM-based AVDs enough to be actually usable?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I need to debug an app that relies on native libraries that have only been compiled for armeabi-v7a and arm64-v8a.  This means I cannot run it on the HAXM emulator (well, I can, but it crashes immediately).  I don't have a physical device with the necessary API level to run the app.  I've tried creating an AVD based off an armeabi-v7a system image, but it takes about 30 minutes to boot up, and when it does, it is so slow to respond that it is unusable.  A single touch or button press takes at least 10 seconds to take effect, and most importantly, adb times out trying to install an app on the device.  I'm not looking to match real device performance, or even the HAXM emulator performance.  Just need to be able to actually install and test an app.

I have tried creating AVDs with various hardware profiles starting with the default specs and up to 4096 MB RAM, 2048 MB heap, 4-core CPU, 4096 MB internal storage, and 800 MB SD card.  I've tried both Hardware and software graphics.
All have been too slow to use.

Is there anything I can do to get an emulated arm device that actually works?  The fact that arm images are offered as an option makes me think there must be a way to use them.  I remember using AVDs before the introduction of the HAXM emulator, and they were nowhere near this slow.  Have the images just become super bloated, or am I doing something wrong?

I'm developing on a machine with an Intel i7 processor, 16GB RAM, 1TB SSD.

Comment: Try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112889/alternatives-to-the-android-avd-emulator). It talks about alternatives to the built in emulator. Hopefully it will help

Answer (score 0):

The only option you have is to patiently search for a compatible hardware. no emulator runs fast. not even the x86 images. if cost is a barrier. you can buy a used device.

Comment: the x86 images may not be "fast", but they are more than performant enough for my purposes.  If I could get an arm image to be run even a quarter as fast, I'd be thrilled.